# How to get attribute from a collection, with multiple objects inside of an array in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, associative-array

I have a collection that contains an array with 2 objects in it. I'm trying to get the `email` attribute, right now there are only 2 objects, but there could be 100 objects, so I'm not sure if I need a loop or if I need to use array_merge, or something.
I've attached a screenshot of the data, I'm not showing the attributes, but just know that one of them is `email`.
I'm die/dumping a variable called `$tokens`.

In the end, it should return a list of emails, for example:

```
john.doe@email.com
jane@email.com
thomas.brown@email.com
```

And I need this logic in the controller, not in the view (.blade), because I'm trying to save this data in a csv file, using fputcsv, that's the main objective and idea here.
[image]

Comment: would help us help you more if you add your controller code.

Comment: Unfortunately, not sure I can, client privacy.

Comment: Create a for such that: `for($i=0; $i<= sizeof($tokens["email"])-1; $i++)` Create an array of emails (`$emails_array = array();`) and array_push all positions like that: `array_push($emails_array, $tokens["email"][$i]);`

Comment: @jagcweb getting error: ```Undefined array key "email"``` from the code inside the ```for()``` brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @jagcweb for the inspiration, his code/answer just needed a couple of tweaks. The following works and does what I was trying to do:

```
$emails_array = array();
for($i=0; $i <= sizeof($tokens)-1; $i++) {
    array_push($emails_array, $tokens[$i]["email"]);
}
```

Now the `$emails_array` contains an array with both emails in it.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like what `pluck` is for:

```
$tokens->pluck('email')
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - `pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck)

Comment: When I do this I get a collection with an empty array inside. It returns this:
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#555 ▼
  #items: []
}